# Count number of occurences based on corresponding column

Tags: r, dplyr

| Category | Value |
| --- | --- |
| First | 100 |
| Second | 150 |
| First | N/A |
| Second | 200 |
| First | 75 |
| Second | N/A |

I would like to count the number of times each value occurs when it has a value. To elaborate, above, both the 'First' and 'Second' column would be equal to 2.

I have tried

```
sum(df$Category == 'First', na.rm=TRUE)
```

but I am very lost. The csv file I have output is a dataframe I have made from a larger data set. I would like to calculate both First and Second or just one of them, they will be equal because it is 3 different categories that are weeks where the 'N/A' values are weeks where data has not been logged yet.

Comment: I don't understand. You refer to "the 'First' and 'Second' column" but those seem to be two values in two rows of the same "Category" column.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(category) %>% filter(value != "N/A") %>% summarize(n())`

Comment: `count(df, Category, wt = !is.na(Value))` -- this will look at the dataframe `df`, group it by `Category`, and count the number of "non-NA's."

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "df" is your dataframe having columns as "category" and "value"

```
df %>% 
  filter(value !='N/A', !is.na(value)) %>%  #filter your data
  count(category)
```

To give you the following data.

```
  category n
1    First 2
2   Second 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of base R options (as there are already good `tidyverse` solutions in the comments):

```
table(df$Category[!is.na(as.numeric(df$Value))])

 #First Second 
 #    2      2
```

Or we could use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(as.numeric(Value) ~ Category, df, NROW, na.action = na.omit)

#  Category as.numeric(Value)
#1    First                 2
#2   Second                 2
```

**Tidyverse**

First, we can convert the `N/A` values to `NA`, then use `count` on the non-NA values.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), na_if, "N/A")) %>% 
  count(Category, wt = !is.na(Value))

#  Category n
#1    First 2
#2   Second 2
```

**Note:** If you are bringing in your data with `read.table` or `read.csv`, then there is `na.strings` option (i.e., `na.strings='N/A'`), which would change the `N/A` to `NA`.

**Data.table**

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, sum(Value != "N/A"), by = Category]
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Category = c("First", "Second", "First", "Second", 
"First", "Second"), Value = c("100", "150", "N/A", "200", "75", 
"N/A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```